# python-sybase how to connect remote server

Tags: python, sybase

I host use the "ip:port",but it throws exception:

Sybase.DatabaseError: Layer: 6, Origin: 8 ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error

py-sybase:0.40pre1
sybase-open_client:15

Any idea? Thanks

Ford

Comment: If i add the $SYBASE/interfaces,sound ok,but it's not good for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import Sybase
>>> help(Sybase.connect)
Help on function connect in module Sybase:

connect(dsn, user, passwd, database=None, strip=0, auto_commit=0, delay_connect=0, locking=1, datetime=None, bulkcopy=0, locale=None, inputmap=None, outputmap=None)
```

The first argument is a DSN, not a hostname.

So, configure a DSN, test it with isql and use it in your script.

Comment: Hi, how do i configure a DSN on windows machine? Do i have to install sybase odbc driver?